# How do I apply box shadow to adjacent elements without the appearance of overlapping?

Tags: html, css

Given this html:

```
<div id="admin_login">
  <form>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
  </form>
  <a href="#">Login</a>
</div>
```

And this css:

```
#admin_login form {
  background: #464950;
  padding: 5px;
  box-shadow: #000 2px 2px 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom:3px;
}

#admin_login input {
  display: block;
  border: none;
  margin: 6px 4px;
  padding: 4px;
}

#admin_login a {
  color: inherit;
  background: #464950;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: #000 2px 2px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

I get this:

[image: overlapping elements]

How can I make the anchor tag and the form appear as one element, instead of overlapping each other?

**UPDATE**

@TristarWebDesign's solution worked perfectly:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean one consistent object, with the login anchor still sticking out, or do you mean making the login anchor in the main box?

Comment: @Sydenam: I guess the former. He just wants the shadow at the top of le login `a` element to disappear. That could be feasible by adjusting the `box-shadow:` attribute's value but I don't think it's very clean to do it this way...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this -

HTML

```
<div id="admin_login">
  <form>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
  </form>
  <div class="login-btn"><a href="#">Login</a></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#admin_login form {
  background: #464950;
  padding: 5px;
  box-shadow: #000 2px 2px 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom:3px;
}

#admin_login input {
  display: block;
  border: none;
  margin: 6px 4px;
  padding: 4px;
}

#admin_login a {
  color: inherit;
  background: #464950;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: #000 2px 2px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#admin_login .login-btn {
    height: 30px;
    margin: -3px 0 0 -4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 0 0 4px;
}
```

Basically just wrapping the link inside a div, setting the div to overflow hidden, and position it in the correct place.

You'll also need to make sure the link is on a layer above the form.

Answer (score 4):

The best solution I've found for this problem is just covering the shadow with a pseudo element...

```
#admin_login a:after {
  /*make  #admin_login a position relative*/
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 0;
  height: 10px;
  background: #464950;
  width: 120%;
}
```

Browsers that support box shadow also support :after, so you're in the clear.

Here is a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/pWD2S/

Comment: Ooh, that’s really clever. I guess you still get a little shadow overlap, but I bet no-one notices it.

Comment: Nice! I had to tweak it a little bit and its not a 100% perfect fix, but its good enough.  Thanks.

Comment: There is no shadow overlap is you position the pseudo-element correctly. Check out the jsfiddle (updated).

Comment: If what you are covering isn't a solid colour, then my method of hiding the overlapping shadow below may be a better option

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/93FXK/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't think this is possible. If there was a css property along the lines of box-shadow-top/right/bottom/left then you may have had a chance.

The easiest way to achieve this is to create the background as a transparent PNG including the drop shadow, and apply it as a background to the containing div.

Comment: Yeah, I had a feeling that might be the case, but I was really hoping to avoid a background image.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party – but I’ve just stumbled upon a very elegant solution to this problem. You can define the `box-shadow` properties not on the elements themselves, but on pseudo elements like `::after`. Like this:

```
#admin_login form::after,
#admin_login a::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;  /* This makes sure the shadow is behind other stuff. */
}

#admin_login form {
  background: #464950;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  position: relative;
}
#admin_login form::after {
  box-shadow: #000 2px 2px 10px;
}


#admin_login input {
  display: block;
  border: none;
  margin: 6px 4px;
  padding: 4px;
}

#admin_login a {
  color: inherit;
  background: #464950;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}
#admin_login a::after {
  box-shadow: #000 2px 2px 10px;
}
```

The idea comes from [a blog post by Michał Dudak](http://blog.dudak.me/2014/css-shadows-under-adjacent-elements/).