# CSS Box Shadow Overlap

Tags: javascript, html, css, box-shadow

I made a sliding puzzle in CSS, which you can view [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ps5aamvw/)

The issue is that I wanted the tiles to have a drop shadow onto the gray background, but I didn't want the shadows to overlap other tiles, since they're all on the same level.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045517/how-do-i-apply-box-shadow-to-adjacent-elements-without-the-appearance-of-overlap#) on StackOverflow, which is really asking the same thing, but I can't seem to get any of the solutions working.

I cannot [cover the overlap with a pseudo-element](http://jsfiddle.net/pWD2S/), because they have background images whose background positions are set in JavaScript. While I could set them using complex CSS selectors that use `nth-child`, I'd rather keep it in JS for now.

I cannot [put the shadow on a pseudo-element underneath the tile](http://blog.dudak.me/2014/css-shadows-under-adjacent-elements/), because I don't know, actually. I tried it in the Fiddle I linked, but it's not working.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```js
// This is the location of the empty square. At the start it's at 2, 2
var emptyRow = 2;
var emptyCol = 2;

// i and j, as passed in, are the tiles' original coordinates
var makeMoveHandler = function (tile, i, j) {
  // row and col, as made here in closure, are the tiles up-to-date coordinates
  var row = i;
  var col = j;

  // The click handler
  return function () {
    var rowOffset = Math.abs(emptyRow - row);
    var colOffset = Math.abs(emptyCol - col);

    // Move the tile to the vacant place next to it
    if (rowOffset == 1 && colOffset == 0 || rowOffset == 0 && colOffset == 1) {
      tile.style.transform = `translate(${emptyCol * 200}px, ${emptyRow * 200}px)`;
      // Swap the two coordinates
      [row, emptyRow] = [emptyRow, row];
      [col, emptyCol] = [emptyCol, col];
    }
  }
};

var initTiles = function () {
  // Get all of the rows
  var rows = document.querySelectorAll('.row');

  // Go through the rows
  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i) {
    var row = rows.item(i);

    // Go through the tiles on each row
    var tiles = row.querySelectorAll('.tile');
    for (let j = 0; j < tiles.length; ++j) {
      var tile = tiles.item(j);

      // Add the click listener to the tile
      tile.addEventListener('click', makeMoveHandler(tile, i, j));

      // Set the location of the tile
      tile.style.transform = `translate(${j * 200}px, ${i * 200}px)`;

      // Set what part of the background to show on the tile
      tile.style.backgroundPosition = `${600 - j * 200}px ${600 - i * 200}px`;
    }
  }
};

// Initialize the tiles
initTiles();
```

```css
#puzzle {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: gray;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

.tile {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: url('http://www.lovethispic.com/uploaded_images/123553-Beautiful-Scene.jpg');
  position: absolute;
  background-size: 600px 600px;
  transition: transform 300ms;
}

.tile:before {
  background: transparent;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -100;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="puzzle">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter: drop-shadow(0 0 40px #000)` on a new element which contains all your rows and tiles:

```
<div id="puzzle">
   <div class="puzzle-inner" style="filter:drop-shadow(0 0 40px #000);">
      <div class="row"> ...
```

This works on the accumulated 'silhouette' of it's contained elements.

This won't work on the `#puzzle` element itself, as it has a background set which will be included in the silhouette.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found 2 methods of solving the problem, both aren't very pretty. I couldn't have a `box-shadow`, and I had come to terms with that. I could, however, create a pseudo-element that contained a picture of a `box-shadow`, so I did that.

I couldn't live with the idea that the browser would have to download an entirely separate image *just for a shadow*, so I made an approximation of a `box-shadow` using CSS3 gradients, which work (at least, in Chrome).

A snippet for the (sort of) simulated `box-shadow`:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
div:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: -20px;
  right: -20px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 220px, black 220px, transparent 240px ),
  linear-gradient(-90deg, transparent 220px, black 220px, transparent 240px );
  z-index: -1;
}
div:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: -20px;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 220px, black 220px, transparent 240px ),
  linear-gradient(180deg, transparent 220px, black 220px, transparent 240px );
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

A [JSFiddle with the sliding puzzle result](https://jsfiddle.net/rpbc5a7c/), since it doesn't work properly in the snippets here.